# how to convert timestamp to date in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to load csv file to snowflake using copy command.
These is a timestamp column in csv file, which I need to convert to date and load to snowflake
any idea on the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Snowflake can convert timestamp to date implicitly. If you get any errors (because of your format), please check the following docs:

Convert Data Types During a Load:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#convert-data-types-during-a-load

TO_DATE function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html

Comment: Just know that converting them during the load will slow down the load.  It is actually faster to load them as strings or timestamps and then convert them in SQL.  However, this answer is definitely the "easiest" way to go.

Answer (score 1):

one of the easy way to convert timestamp into date in snowflake is
If you have created_date = 2023-10-18 08:36:59.098
you want 2023-10-18

cast(CREATED_DT AS Date)
it will returns you only date. I hope it will help
[image]